# React env - Strings with spaces get cut off

Tags: reactjs, shell, dotenv

I made a React app that I want to build for different servers / customers.
I created a folder `configurations` with different `.env` files. E.g.: `.env.foo`, `.env.bar`, `.env.tree`, `.env.mirror`, `.env.backup`.

To point three values out as an example I have:

```
REACT_OWNER_NAME=Malcom X
REACT_OWNER_MAIL=mx@mail.com
REACT_FTP_FOLDER_PATH=foo.domain.com
```

In my `App.js` I have

```
const App = () => {
   return (
      <>
         {process.env.REACT_OWNER_NAME}<br />
         {process.env.REACT_OWNER_MAIL}
      </>
   );
}
```

Now I want to place each `configurations/.env*` file in the root, build the app and deploy it to the different servers.

To automate this, I build the following `builder.sh` script:

```
mv .env env

for CURR in foo bar tree mirror backup

do
    cp configurations/.env.$CURR .env
    export $(cat .env | grep -v '#' | awk '/=/ {print $1}')
    if [ -z ${REACT_FTP_FOLDER_NAME+x} ]; then foldername=$CURR; else foldername=$REACT_FTP_FOLDER_NAME; fi

    yarn build
    
    mkdir apps/${foldername}
    mv build/* apps/${foldername}/.
    rm -rf build
    
    mv .env apps/${foldername}/.env
done
mv env .env
```

Now my issue: When I run the script with `for CURR in foo`, then `for CURR in bar` and so on (each file one by one) I have no issue, I get all the apps build into `apps/`.
But when I run it with `for CURR in foo bar tree mirror backup` the output is the same, but when I log `process.env` all variables containing a space get cut off by the space.
When I just `yarn build` the apps, no issue. When I add "" around the strings I get `REACT_OWNER_NAME: "\Malcom"`.

In every case when I compare `configurations/.env.foo` with `apps/foo.domain.com/.env` there is no difference between the files.

And the funnies thing... the first app (in this example foo) is correct.